# The set of all polynomials whose coefficient of $x^2$ is a multiple of 3.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

Here is the question I am trying to know its correct answer:

Let $I \subset \mathbb Z[x]$ be the set of all polynomials whose coefficient of $x^2$ is a multiple of 3. Is $I$ an ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$?

**My solution:**

Yes it is, as it is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z[x]$ and it absorbs the elements of $\mathbb Z.$ but my professor told me that this is wrong.

Could someone clarify to me why this is wrong please?

Comment: What does it mean to absorb the elements of $\mathbb Z$?  You need to show that the elements of $I$ are closed under multiplication by general ring elements (or show that this does not hold).

Comment: @lulu yes that is what I showed, multiplying by any nonzero element of $\mathbb Z$ will keep the coefficient of  $x^2$ a multiple of 3.

Comment: Can you state the definition of an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$?

Comment: My friend, try harder. What is the product of two degree 1 polynomials? Are they in $I$?

Comment: @user24142 oh I thought that our ring is $\mathbb Z $ only

Comment: $I$ isn't even a subset of $\mathbb Z$.  $3x^2+x+1\in I$.

Comment: The notation you have used usually denotes the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, with 'variable' x. If you intend for it to mean something else, you should let us know.

Comment: No I did not mean anything else @user24142

Comment: So, for instance, $x \in I$. Is the product of that element of $I$ with itself in $I$?

Comment: Hint: if $I$ is an ideal then $\,I\ni f = f_0 +f_1 x+ \cdots \Rightarrow x^2f,\,xf \in I\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid f_0,f_1\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that your subset $I\subset \mathbb Z[X]$ is an ideal, it must be checked that $I$ is closed under addition (i.e. that it is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z[X]$, which is true) and that $I$ is closed under multiplication by any element in $\mathbb Z[X]$ (not only by elements in $\mathbb Z$, as you wrote).

For example, $3X^2+X\in I$; but $X\cdot (3X^2+X)=3X^3+X^2\notin I$.